# How to change default DDS during ros2 source compiling?

Tags: ros2, build-from-source, dds

I'm building ros2 humble from source, I would like to change the default DDS to `rmw_cyclonedds_cpp`, so with my self built version of ROS2, the user does not have to specify `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` and use `rmw_cyclonedds_cpp` as default.

What source change do I need to or to set some environment variable during ROS2 source building?

I have read this, but did not find the answer for my need.

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Working-with-multiple-RMW-implementations.html

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. In my opinion, it is a runtime specification. Maybe you can just create a "run.sh" file. In this file, you set the RMW_IMPLEMENTATION variable and launch your nodes.

Comment: @AntoineVanMalleghem even if I'm compiling ROS2 from source and I can change the ROS2 source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanisms for controlling RMW implementation selection are handled in the [`rmw_implementation` package](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation) .

At the time that you are building `rmw_implementation`, it checks the CMake variable `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` to determine which will be the "default" for that build.

Since we are building with cmake, you can pass it as a flag to the cmake invocation `cmake .. -DRMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp`.  CMake flags can also be passed via `colcon` with: `--cmake-args` or `--ament-cmake-args`:

```
colcon build --ament-cmake-args -DRMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
```